# How do I add monitor resolution options to Pixel?

Tags: display, pixel

I only have about 4 or 5 monitor resolutions on the configuration screen for my Raspberry Pi. I have seen pictures online where people have dozens of them. Where is this reading them from? How can I add my monitors so I can more easily switch between them instead of having to manually edit the config.txt file?